# Perl, CGI::Session 4.35, "Don't know where to store the id" error

Tags: perl, cgi

I am writing a web application that needs to use Session capability. I strictly only have access to module CGI::Session version 4.35 
([backpan archive](http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/M/MA/MARKSTOS/CGI-Session-4.35.tar.gz), [closest version on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Session-4.40/)).

When trying to use the module, specifically running this statement to create a new session (or retrieving the previous session):

```
use CGI::Session ('-ip_match');
…
$session = CGI::Session->new("id:incr", undef, {Directory => '/tmp'})
```

I'm having this error which I can't seem to find anywhere else:

> Don't know where to store the id at (some_location)/x86-32.linux.2.6/5.8/lib/perl5/CGI/Session.pm line 79\n

I sense that this error is caused within the module itself, not from my code. Could you please confirm this?

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use [CGI::Session::ID::incr](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aSession%3a%3aID%3a%3aincr) and that module requires an IDFile argument so that it knows where to store the ID data.

```
use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match' );    

...

$session = CGI::Session->new("id:incr",undef,
                             {Directory=>'/tmp',IDFile => '/tmp/id.file'});
```